# ASP.net MVC Increase the Application session timeout

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, timeout, session-timeout, application-pool

net MVC5 application with SQL 2014 (database) .It is hosted in IaaS ( in Azure Cloud ). I have set the Session state time out value as 120 Min and application pool idle time out as 120 Min. Then Noticed that the session expires/time out expired after 60 Minutes . Though I set the Session and Application pool idle time as 120 Minutes . In my Data Access Layer I am using the "Transaction" and it is looks like it is failing to Save the transaction . Please advice how can improve this . I wanted my application should work if the user keep idle for around 2 hours .